# Any way to reverse engineer path from dropbox share link?

Tags: dropbox

I have a dropbox share link and accidentally renamed/moved the folder that it's linking to. I have given people the link and am trying to figure some way to figure out what the path was so I can put things back the way they were?

I have tried toggling 'show deleted' in the directory in question, and tried putting all the folders in question, and none of those are working